# How to represent pm.request.body from postman in python

Tags: python, postman

I want to hash a dictionary in python 2.7 to obtain the same result as I get in postman by calling pm.request body. The hashing method works correctly when I try with strings, but I can't get the body to hash the same. I'm using OrderedDictionary from collections package in python. I assumed that the pm.body.request would be a JSON but it does not seem to be the case.

pm-body

```
{
  "personNumber": "195012161930",
  "requestDescription": "Detta ar ett test",
  "verksamhetId": "1ac12a80-819a-42ca-bd51-97bd3e19c443",
  "stadsDelID": "f55a5bea-2398-11e9-8140-0e9ccdb68c09"
}
```

Pre-request script in PM

```
var hmacKey = 'c811f8ae-dd9f-4b15-9a09-97a09bdbb485'; 

var contentToHash = pm.request.body.raw;
var cryptoJs = require('crypto-js'); 
var hash = cryptoJs.HmacSHA256(contentToHash, hmacKey); 
var hashInBase64 = cryptoJs.enc.Base64.stringify(hash); 
  
console.log(hashInBase64 + " This is the result");
```

What I've tried in Python

```
        key = "c811f8ae-dd9f-4b15-9a09-97a09bdbb485"

        od = OrderedDict() 
        od['personNumber'] = "195012161111"
        od['requestDescription'] = "Detta ar ett test"
        od['verksamhetId'] = "1ac12a80-819a-42ca-bd51-97bd3e19c443"
        od['stadsDelID'] = "f55a5bea-2398-11e9-8140-0e9ccdb68c09"

        contentToHash = (json.dumps((od)))

        hash = hmac.new( key, (contentToHash), hashlib.sha256)
        
        baseHash = base64.b64encode(hash.digest())
        print(baseHash + " This is the result in Python")
```

This is the expected value for hashInBase64 after running the Pre-request script '25iZC8NycCILZJCGN9T2jachFANGD4HkLSp+8X0W/Jk='

Comment: whats the value of hmacKey and key

Comment: I updated the code with the keys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution for your problem:**

**Python2:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

key = bytearray("c811f8ae-dd9f-4b15-9a09-97a09bdbb485","utf-8")

od = OrderedDict() 
od['personNumber'] = "195012161930"
od['requestDescription'] = "Detta ar ett test"
od['verksamhetId'] = "1ac12a80-819a-42ca-bd51-97bd3e19c443"
od['stadsDelID'] = "f55a5bea-2398-11e9-8140-0e9ccdb68c09"

contentToHash = json.dumps(od,indent=2,separators=(',', ': '))

contentToHash = contentToHash.replace("\n","\r\n")

print(repr(contentToHash))

hash = hmac.new( key, (contentToHash).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)

baseHash = base64.b64encode(hash.digest())
print(str(baseHash) + " This is the result in Python")
```

**Python3:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

key = bytearray("c811f8ae-dd9f-4b15-9a09-97a09bdbb485","utf-8")

od = OrderedDict() 
od['personNumber'] = "195012161930"
od['requestDescription'] = "Detta ar ett test"
od['verksamhetId'] = "1ac12a80-819a-42ca-bd51-97bd3e19c443"
od['stadsDelID'] = "f55a5bea-2398-11e9-8140-0e9ccdb68c09"

contentToHash = json.dumps(od,indent="\r  ",separators=(',', ': '))

contentToHash=contentToHash.replace("\n\r","\r\n")
contentToHash = contentToHash.replace("\n}","\r\n}")

print(repr(contentToHash))

hash = hmac.new( key, (contentToHash).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)

baseHash = base64.b64encode(hash.digest())
print(str(baseHash) + " This is the result in Python")
```

**Postman:**

```
var hmacKey = 'c811f8ae-dd9f-4b15-9a09-97a09bdbb485'; 

var contentToHash = pm.request.body.raw;
console.log(JSON.stringify(contentToHash))
var cryptoJs = require('crypto-js'); 
var hash = cryptoJs.HmacSHA256(contentToHash, hmacKey); 
var hashInBase64 = cryptoJs.enc.Base64.stringify(hash); 
  
console.log(hashInBase64 + " This is the result");
```

**The correct approach:**

**You should remove spaces to make it work across all applications :**

pm.request.body doesn't return just the body content but  the full body object with the content type

so you should use

```
pm.request.body.raw
```

But still this will have space in it  , you can remove it using

```
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw))
```

Now the same space issue is there in the python code you can remove it using

```
contentToHash = json.dumps(od,separators=(',', ':'))
```

**Python code:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

key = bytearray("c811f8ae-dd9f-4b15-9a09-97a09bdbb485","utf-8")

od = OrderedDict() 
od['personNumber'] = "195012161111"
od['requestDescription'] = "Detta ar ett test"
od['verksamhetId'] = "1ac12a80-819a-42ca-bd51-97bd3e19c443"
od['stadsDelID'] = "f55a5bea-2398-11e9-8140-0e9ccdb68c09"

contentToHash = json.dumps(od,separators=(',', ':'))

hash = hmac.new( key, (contentToHash).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)

baseHash = base64.b64encode(hash.digest())
print(str(baseHash) + " This is the result in Python")
```

**Postman pre-request:**

```
var hmacKey = 'c811f8ae-dd9f-4b15-9a09-97a09bdbb485'; 

var contentToHash = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw),null,null)

var cryptoJs = require('crypto-js'); 
var hash = cryptoJs.HmacSHA256(contentToHash, hmacKey); 
console.log(hash)
var hashInBase64 = cryptoJs.enc.Base64.stringify(hash); 
  
console.log(hashInBase64 + " This is the result");
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225383/discussion-on-answer-by-pdhide-how-to-represent-pm-request-body-from-postman-in).